# Not able to fetch the relationship with Many to many association using spring-data JPA,

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have been developing an application using Spring. I am using a HSQL database and I am using spring data JPA for ORM. I have a User and a Movie entity which are associated with a many to many relationship. In the Database I have created a user, movie and a UserMovieRelation table.

#### Database tables

```
    create table users (
        user_id varchar(20) not null,
        user_Name varchar(255),
        description varchar(255),
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
     );

   create table movies (
       movie_Id varchar(20) not null,
       movie_name varchar(255),
       description varchar(255),
       movie_Type varchar(255),
       language varchar(255),
       PRIMARY KEY (movie_Id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE UserMovieRelation(
       user_id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       movie_Id varchar(20) NOT NULL,
       FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id), 
       FOREIGN KEY (movie_Id) REFERENCES movies(movie_Id),
       PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_Id)
    );
```

#### User entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
----------
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "UserMovieRelation", 
joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_Id") })
private Set<Movie> movies;
------
}
```

#### Movie entity

```
@Entity
        @Table(name="movies")
        public class Movie implements Serializable {
          --------
          @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
          private Set<User> users;
          --------
        }
```

I have two repositories: UserRepository and MovieRepository respectively.

In my service class I am returning all the users via findAll method of spring data JPA.

```
public List<User> getAllUser() {
         return userRepository.findAll();
    }
```

But I am not able to fetch the movie details associated with the user in the UserMovieRelation table. Though the table has all the data.

```
    USER_ID MOVIE_ID 
    ------- -------- 
     1       1       
     1       2
```

The output is coming as

```
    [
        {
           "userId": "1",
           "userName": "default",
           "userDesc": "default desc",
           "movies": []
        }
    ]
```

As you can see, Movie detail is empty. What am I doing it wrong, how to fetch the movie details in the output?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to change your annotation from

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
```

To

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
```

This eager fetch will also query all related products and fill in your empty movies list.

Comment: I have tried this option also. Its not working either. List is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

`@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })` in the `User` class